# Batch remove old profiles

Tags: batch-file

I need a script (without delprof.exe) to remove windows xp profiles older than 1 year. I use CCleaner first to remove all temp files in windows and the user profile.

```
start /wait ccleaner.exe /auto
```

Then I want to remove profiles. But simply rmdir won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set /a YYYYprev=%YYYY%-1
wmic path win32_userprofile where "not LocalPath like '%Admin%' and special=false and loaded=false and LastUseTime<'%YYYYPrev%%MM%%DD%'" delete
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I run this it will also delete the default, administrator account. That folders are older than 1 year. They can't be deleted.

Comment: Simple enough to filter out admin accounts. See edit

Answer (score 1):

#### Look like can edit the registry directly, use wmic, powershell, group policy, or 3rd party tools:

- [windows-7-delprof-replacement-for-deleting-profiles](https://serverfault.com/questions/195043/windows-7-delprof-replacement-for-deleting-profiles)
- [how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain](https://superuser.com/questions/63017/how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156826
- [delprof2](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/)

Comment: Thank your for the reply. But its Windows XP. Windows 7 cleanup script wont work.

Comment: Just because Windows 7 is listed in the link titles does not mean that the options will not work on Windows XP.  Please familiarize yourself with the options listed before assuming.  FYI: the answer you selected uses the same wmic command as listed in my first link.  While delprof2 does not work with XP there may be other 3rd party apps that do.  Also registry and powershell should work on XP. Try and learn instead of just demanding "I need a script".

Comment: Hi David. Its my statement to learn everyday something new. I've read the links. Thanks.