# Batch - how to loop through profiles to remove uninstaller executable

Tags: loops, batch-file, uninstallation

I have a piece of software that is on user profile directory under AppData\Local\AceSoftware
The uninstaller is AceUninstall.exe
Sometimes its in multiple folders.
Ex:

```
AppData\Local\AceSoftware\20200101\AceUninstall.exe
AppData\Local\AceSoftware\20191201\AceUninstall.exe
AppData\Local\AceSoftware\20191101\AceUninstall.exe
```

I am new to batch but I put together a working script and it loops through each AceSoftware folder and uninstalls the AceUninstall.exe.

The only issue is, it only does it for the profile I'm logged on to.
Could anyone tell me how to have this same script loop through ALL profiles?

Here is what I have so far:

```
for /d %%D in (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\AceSoftware\*) do (
"%%D\AceUninstall.exe" /uninstall /silent
)
```

It does a great job but for only the profile I'm logged into.
I need to use a batch file for this so I can deploy it through SCCM.
Thank you ahead of time

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21855512/62576) shows some ways you can iterate through user profiles from a batch file.

Comment: Well obviously in order to loop through all profile directories, you'd need to run the script as a user with sufficient permissions to access and delete. All you need to do is to research how to get a listing of all user profile locations. Alternatively, if you're only working with local profiles, you can simply perform a search for `AceUninstall.exe`, check that `\AceSoftware\ ` is contained within its path, and then perform the deletion like that.